# Extract constant string from type field at compile time

Tags: typescript

I have a type with a field that has a constant string literal. I would like to reference my type and field by name to use this string literal elsewhere in my code. For example:

```js
export type MyType = {
    action?: 'TestAction';
    arg0: true,
};

/////

let input: any = {
    action: 'XYZ',
};

if (input.action === MyType.action) { // This obviously does not work
    // TODO: perform TestAction
}
```

Is there anyway to accomplish this, outside of moving `'TestAction'` to its own const definition?

Comment: `MyType` is a type, so no, this is not possible. You can't extract JS values from TS types, only the reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare the type as a constant and refer to in both places

```
const ActionType = "TestAction";

export type MyType = {
  action?: typeof ActionType;
  arg0: true;
};

/////

let input: any = {
  action: "XYZ",
};

if (input.action === ActionType) {
  // This obviously does not work
  // TODO: perform TestAction
}
```

Another option would be to use a switch statement (optionally coercing the type to pick up from your `MyType` typing, i.e.

```
export type MyType = {
    action?: 'TestAction';
    arg0: true,
};


/////

let input: any = {
    action: 'XYZ',
};

switch (input.action as MyType['action']) {
    case 'TestAction':
        // perform TestAction
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: This was what I came up with too. It requires changing the definition of `MyType`, something I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: The other option would be to use a switch statement and keep the definition, I've updated my example to demonstrate

Answer (score 0):

You can't use anything in TS land at runtime, so a `const` definition is probably your best bet. If you don't want to change the definition of `MyType`, you could do this:

```
// Enforce consistency with MyType's definition
const TEST_ACTION: MyType['action'] = 'TestAction';
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyiAqzUF44DeAUHKXAIYDGMAlhAHYD8AXHAOSbADOMAgtXXpsA3CTLkoAcwAMrGFACuwADREAvqKIB6HTqJEANsHg16YBTFbl6iOPmJkKAhqzYANAJoAtNqo37KBh44TABRAGVMAH1eAGFMAEkAeQA5VgxsFABtNipaBjYAXTt2Th5%20fKFNGgAzOAAKU3MYADo8wTtcfDDImPjklIBKQjgxHRCkgBEk9SA).